# Android studio does not recognize java statements/JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0, android-studio-4.1

After updating android studio to the latest version, alongside plugins and gradle, android studio cannot recognize java statements. There would be an error on all import statements like "`import java.util.ArrayList;`"
I'm using **java 14.0.2**, and the newest build of **android studio 4.1.**
[The error message "can't resolve symbol arraylist"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHnjy.png)
[Other error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EveU0.png)

---

I've tried re-installing android studio with admin permission(deleted the .gradle and .android folder in my appdata)
I've tried re-installed the JDK and SDK
I've check the route of sdk and jdk location
I've tried to invalidate all cache/restart
[I've made sure that these are the correct directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4MQ0.png)
Is there anything else I should give a shot at? thanks!
(android gradle version is 6.5, gradle plugin version is 4.1.0)

Comment: how did you resolved this issue. I am also facing the same error now in my mac.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and errors, I found a folder called "google" inside my c drive, in it is an android folder. Deleting the android folder and re-opening android studio prompted me to redownload a lot of stuff, afterwards it went back to normal.

Comment: I am having the same issue, which "google" folder exactly? what was its content?

Comment: Its a folder in my c drive, under program and files(x86),  not too sure if there would also be a folder in the same location for you though. If you cant find it maybe try just searching "Android" or "Google" in your entire drive